# Another integral $\int \frac{3 x^2+2 x+1}{ \left(x^3+x^2+x+2\right) \sqrt{1+\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x+2}}} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, indefinite-integrals

Here is an indefinite integral that is similar to an integral I wanna propose for a contest. Apart from 
using CAS, do you see any very easy way of calculating it?

$$\int \frac{1+2x +3 x^2}{\left(2+x+x^2+x^3\right) \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+x+x^2+x^3}}} \, dx$$

**EDIT:** It's a part from the generalization

$$\int \frac{1+2x +3 x^2+\cdots n x^{n-1}}{\left(2+x+x^2+\cdots+ x^n\right) \sqrt{1\pm\sqrt{2+x+x^2+\cdots +x^n}}} \, dx$$

**Supplementary question:** How would you calculate the following integral using the generalization above? Would you prefer another way?

$$\int_0^{1/2} \frac{1}{\left(x^2-3 x+2\right)\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{x-2}{x-1}}+1} } \, dx$$

As a note, the generalization like the one you see above and slightly modified versions can be wisely used for calculating very hard integrals.

Comment: where have you been. Why are you not frequent on chat?

Comment: things have been quiet on chat... too quiet ;-)

Answer (score 9):

HINT:

As $\dfrac{d(2+x+x^2+x^3)}{dx}=1+2x+3x^2,$

let  $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+x+x^2+x^3}}=u\implies 2+x+x^2+x^3=(u^2-1)^2$

and $(1+2x+3x^2)dx=(u^2-1)2u\ du$

Now use [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html),

$\dfrac1{(u^2-1)^2}=\dfrac A{u-1}+\dfrac B{(u-1)^2}+\dfrac C{u+1}+\dfrac D{(u+1)^2}$

Answer (score 5):

Let $$2+x+x^2+x^3=t^2\implies (1+2x+3x^2)dx=2tdt$$ $$\int \frac{2tdt}{t^2\sqrt{1+t}}$$ $$=2\int \frac{dt}{t\sqrt{1+t}}$$
Let $1+t=x^2\implies dt=2xdx$
$$=2\int \frac{2xdx}{(x^2-1)x}$$
$$=4\int \frac{dx}{x^2-1}$$
$$=4\int \frac{dx}{(x-1)(x+1)}$$
$$=4\frac{1}{2}\int \left(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)dx$$
$$=4\frac{1}{2}\left(\int\frac{dx}{x-1}-\int\frac{dx}{x+1}\right)$$
$$=2\left(\ln|x-1|-\ln|x+1|\right)+c$$

$$=2\ln\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right|+c$$
$$=2\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{1+t}-1}{\sqrt{1+t}+1}\right|+c$$
$$=2\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+2+x+x^2+x^3}}-1}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+2+x+x^2+x^3}}+1}\right|+c$$

Comment: It should be $\sqrt{1+\sqrt t}$ right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot Thanks for sharing (+1).

Answer (score 3):

Let $\sinh^4(t)=x^3+x^2+x+2$. Then $\cosh(t)=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x+2}}$ and
$$
\begin{align}
&\int\frac{3x^2+2x+1}{\left(x^3+x^2+x+2\right)\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x+2}}} \,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}\sinh^4(t)}{\sinh^4(t)\cosh(t)}\\
&=4\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sinh(t)}\\
&=4\int\frac{\mathrm{d}\cosh(t)}{\cosh^2(t)-1}\\
&=2\int\left(\frac1{\cosh(t)-1}-\frac1{\cosh(t)+1}\right)\mathrm{d}\cosh(t)\\[2pt]
&=2\log\left(\frac{\cosh(t)-1}{\cosh(t)+1}\right)+C\\[6pt]
&=-4\operatorname{arccoth}(\cosh(t))+C\\[6pt]
&=-4\operatorname{arccoth}\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x+2}}\right)+C
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Nice way to go (+1)